# Wait for signal from parent and does job and blocks again

Tags: linux, signals, posix, ipc

Write a program that can display a text string (consisting only of the 26 alphabets and spaces).  The program should fork 27 worker processes.  Each worker process runs an infinite loop in which it waits for a signal from the controller (i.e., parent), sleeps for 1 sec, prints its pre-defined character, signals the controller, then blocks again. The controller reads a string from the keyboard, then signals the workers in the correct order to get the string displayed
The following is my code, but I am not getting output, it isn't printing anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
int
main()
{
  /*...declarations and stuff....*/
  scanf("%s",inputString);
  length=strlen(inputString);
  for (i=0;i<27;i++)
  {
    pid[i]=fork();
    if (pid[i]==0)
     {
       /*...Declare my character...*/
       while (1)
       {
          pause();
          sleep(1);
          printf("%c",myChar);
          kill(ppid,SIGCONT);
       }
       return 0;
     }
  }
  for (i=0;i<length;i++)
  {
    int temp=inputString[i];
    if (temp==32)
    {
      kill(pid[0],SIGCONT);
    }
    else
    {
      kill(pid[temp-96],SIGCONT);
    }
    pause();
  }
  for(i=0;i<27;i++)
    kill(pid[i],SIGTERM);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: for(i=0;i<27;i++)
    kill(pid[i],SIGTERM);
  return 0;
trying to kill init process(pid 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First never use `SIGCONT` or another signal like this for custom usage. Prefer using `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`. `SIGCONT` has some special semantic.
2. Now even if you change `CONT` to, say, `USR1`, the way you use `pause()` is a problem. After the child process been awaked, it will be killed because you didn't catched signals. Manual says:

> **`pause()`** causes the calling process (or thread) to sleep until a
>          signal is delivered that either terminates the process or causes the
>          invocation of a signal-catching function.

3. Children will never signal the right process as you did not set `ppid` to a correct value.
4. You will never experienced printings correctly because writes are buffered and there is no flushing. Either use `printf("%c",myChar); fflush(stdout);` or `printf("%c\n",myChar);`

That will lead to something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

void handler(int sig) {
}

int main() {
  pid_t ppid;
  int length;
  char inputString[256];
  pid_t pid[256];
  int i;
  char myChar;
  scanf("%s",inputString);
  length=strlen(inputString);
  struct sigaction action;
  sigemptyset(&(action.sa_mask));
  action.sa_flags = 0;
  action.sa_handler = handler;
  sigaction(SIGUSR1,&action,NULL);
  ppid = getpid();
  for (i=0;i<27;i++) {
    pid[i]=fork();
    if (pid[i]==0) {
       myChar='a'+i;
       while (1) {
          pause();
          sleep(1);
          printf("%c\n",myChar);
          kill(ppid,SIGUSR1);
       }
       return 0;
     }
  }
  for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
    int temp=inputString[i];
    if (temp==32) {
      kill(pid[0],SIGUSR1);
    }
    else {
      kill(pid[temp-'a'],SIGUSR1);
    }
    pause();
  }
  for(i=0;i<27;i++)
    kill(pid[i],SIGTERM);
  return 0;
}
```

5. There is little much more thing to say, like *why looping over 27?*, etc, but these are actually minor problems (this not to say not to correct them later).

Comment: It seems to me you'd want to use [`sigsuspend`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsuspend.html) or `sigwait` to avoid a [race condition with `pause`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pause-Problems.html).